# Embedding background audio in html on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I experimented several codes but none of them did work. Traditional play audio tags don't work neither. I  want to simply embed an background audio on an html page and I don't want a player graphics to be seen. I guess I need Javascript for that. I need a code help that starts as 'add this piece of code onto the header section of your html file'.

Comment: This question isn't related to iOS. It's HTML5 and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you can not do so, without a user action.

The normal scripts that you are looking at with JavaScript will not auto play on ios devices.  You need to have a user action, such as a click to start button that will begin playing the audio.